# What is the "combinatorial coboundary" in Cech cohomology?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In David R. Morrison's *The Clemens-Schmid exact sequence and applications*, we have a singular variety $\mathfrak{X}_0$ which is the union of irreducible components $\{X_i\}_i$ with each $X_i$ smooth.

For some collection of indices $i_0,\ldots,i_p$, write $X_{i_0\ldots i_p} := X_{i_0}\cap \cdots\cap X_{i_p}$, and $\mathfrak{X}^{[p]} := \bigsqcup_{i_0 < i_1 < \cdots < i_p} X_{i_0\ldots i_p}$. Let $\iota_p : \mathfrak{X}^{[p]}\rightarrow\mathfrak{X}$ be the natural map. For a suitable open cover $\mathfrak{U}$ of $\mathfrak{X}_0$, consider the groups of Cech cochains
$$E_0^{p,q} := \check{C}^q(\iota_p^{-1}(\mathfrak{U}),\mathbb{Q})$$
Now he denotes by $d : E_0^{p,q}\rightarrow E_0^{p,q+1}$ the Cech coboundary. He denotes by $\delta : E_0^{p,q}\rightarrow E_0^{p-1,q}$ the "combinatorial coboundary induced by"
$$\delta\phi(V\cap X_{j_0\ldots j_{q+1}}) = \sum_a (-1)^q\phi(V\cap X_{j_0\ldots\hat{j_a}\ldots j_{q+1}})$$
Is this a typo? I'm failing to see how the right hand side defines an element of $E_0^{p-1,q}$. What is $V$? What am I missing? (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9qws.jpg) for a partial scan of the article containing the exact text I'm asking about).

Comment: I think it makes sense, but the notation is poor. First ask yourself, what is an element of the cochain group?

Comment: @ZhenLin As I understand it an element of $E^{p-1,q}$ takes as input a Cech $q$-simplex (here a $(q+1)$-tuple of opens on $\mathfrak{X}^{[p]}$), and outputs a locally constant function on their intersection. I don't see how $V\cap X_{j_0\ldots j_{q+1}}$ can be interpreted as a $q$-simplex, unless they're using another notion of Cech cohomology? It might also help to know what $V$ is supposed to be...

Comment: Well, conventionally, $V$ is an open subspace of something. (Presumably $V$ for voisinage.) So $V \cap X_{j_0 \ldots j_{q+1}}$ is an open subspace of $X_{j_0 \ldots j_{q+1}}$, and $X_{j_0 \ldots j_{q+1}}$ is a summand (disjointunionand?) of $X^{[p]}$, so it fits.

Comment: @ZhenLin How is $X_{j_0\ldots j_{q+1}}$ a "disjointunionand" of $X^{[p]}$? There is no relation betwen $p$ and $q$ right? For example if $p = 0$ and $q = 0$ then $X_{j_0j_1}$ would be codimension 1 in $X^{[0]} = \sqcup X_i$, so it's hardly a "disjointunionand". Am I being stupid?

Comment: Sorry, I was not paying enough attention to the notation. There are too many objects involved and it is easier to have a mental model than to write it all down and communicate it.

Answer (score 1):

I will discuss a more general situation than the particular situation you are asking about, so the notation will not match up exactly.

First things first.
Whenever we have a space $X$ that is a union of subspaces $Y_i$, we can form a simplicial object $X_\bullet$ that is in degree $p$ given by $X_p = \coprod (Y_{i_0} \cap \cdots \cap Y_{i_p})$.
The face operators are induced by the inclusions $Y_{i_0} \cap \cdots \cap Y_{i_p} \hookrightarrow Y_{i_0} \cap \cdots \cap \widehat{Y_{i_\alpha}} \cap \cdots \cap Y_{i_p}$ and the degeneracy operators similarly.
(I hope you understand what I mean.
There is simply no good way of notating this without introducing a lot of auxiliary objects.)
In fact, $X_\bullet$ has an augmentation $X_\bullet \to X$ and we can pull back any open cover $\mathfrak{U}$ of $X$ to obtain an open cover $\mathfrak{U}_p$ on each $X_p$ that is compatible with the simplicial operators.
Thus, applying the Čech cochain complex functor, we obtain a cosimplicial cochain complex $\check{C}{}^q (\mathfrak{U}_p)$, and then as usual we can take the alternating sum of coface operators to obtain a second coboundary operator, and hence a double cochain complex.

Somewhat more concretely, an element $\phi$ of $\check{C}{}^q (\mathfrak{U}_p)$ is an assignment of a scalar function $\phi_{i_0, \ldots, i_p, U_0, \ldots, U_q}$ on $U_0 \cap \cdots \cap U_q \cap Y_{i_0} \cap \cdots \cap Y_{i_p}$ to each tuple $(i_0, \ldots, i_p, U_0, \ldots, U_q)$ where $i_0, \ldots, i_p$ are indices and $U_0, \ldots, U_q$ are elements of the open cover $\mathfrak{U}$.
The coboundary operator $\check{C}{}^q (\mathfrak{U}_p) \to \check{C}{}^q (\mathfrak{U}_{p+1})$ must therefore take assignments of functions to tuples of the form $(i_0, \ldots, i_p, U_0, \ldots, U_q)$ to assignments of functions to tuples of the form $(i_0, \ldots, i_{p+1}, U_0, \ldots, U_q)$.
There is basically only one sensible way of doing this: given $(i_0, \ldots, i_{p+1}, U_0, \ldots, U_q)$, for each $0 \le \alpha \le p+1$, omit $i_\alpha$, take the function assigned to that tuple, multiply it by $(-1)^\alpha$, and then take the sum.
Symbolically, the coboundary of $\phi$ is the assignment
$$(i_0, \ldots, i_{p+1}, U_0, \ldots, U_q) \mapsto \sum_{0 \le \alpha \le p+1} (-1)^\alpha \phi_{i_0, \ldots, \widehat{i_\alpha}, \ldots, i_{p+1}, U_0, \ldots, U_q}$$
which is more or less what appears in the cited article, but with slightly different notation and perhaps some typos.